# Windows Application .exe into AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, client

I use a 3D rendering program, the program is licensed and comes in an .exe file format where I need to install both a server and a client on premise to run the software.

At the moment, the setup requires a server PC + multiple client PCs. So currently it looks like this:

3D rendering program < FTP-server < Run application on client PC

Ideally, I would like to set this up as

3D rendering program < Cloud < Windows Remote Desktop connect

What would be a good way to progress and explore the options around moving to AWS from the FTP server? Is it a good idea to install both server and client? Would appreciate input from anyone who has implemented a similar project before.

Many YouTube videos out there to suggest this is possible, but nothing to demo the end state and validate the next logical steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never implemented a similar project before, so hopefully someone with experience in this field will chime in.

My initial thought was that you are looking for a virtual machine with graphics acceleration capabilities. In AWS cloud, graphics intensive applications are speciality of Amazon **EC2 G4** instances. Please see the specification [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/g4/).

> Amazon EC2 G4 instances are the industry’s most cost-effective and
> versatile GPU instances for deploying machine learning models such as
> image classification, object detection, and speech recognition, and
> for graphics-intensive applications such as remote graphics
> workstations, game streaming, and graphics rendering. G4 instances are
> available with a choice of NVIDIA GPUs (G4dn) or AMD GPUs (G4ad).

You can connect to an EC2 G4 instance with Remote Desktop Protocol, but also with [Teradici PCoIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teradici) or [NICE DCV](https://aws.amazon.com/hpc/dcv/) protocols.

[image: how-it-works]

You can find a [setup guidance here](https://pages.awscloud.com/ec2-virtual-workstations-media-entertainment.html).

As an alternative, if you don't need something as powerfull, you can set up **Windows-based EC2 instance with [Elastic Graphics accelerators](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/elastic-graphics/)** and connect to your virtual machine using [the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html).

> Elastic Graphics supports OpenGL 4.3 on Microsoft Windows Server 2012
> R2 or later and offers graphics accelerators with up to 8 GiB of GPU
> memory, making them ideally suited for any workload that needs a small
> amount of acceleration such as virtual desktops, gaming, industrial
> design, or HPC visualization.
>
> For workloads that require workstation-class graphics, flexibility
> across operating systems, and support across graphics APIs, [Amazon
> EC2 G4 instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/g4/)
> deliver the industry’s most cost-effective and versatile GPU instance.